# What would be the voltage reading at point B when the circuit is supplied with two different voltages?

Tags: voltage, current, circuit-design, voltage-divider, multimeter

The given circuit has one fixed resistor connected in series with a bulb. When 12V is supplied, there is a reading of 8V at point B.

However, when the same circuit is supplied with another source of 12V, there is 12V reading at point B. The simple reason is that current take the path of shortest route, thereby acting as a short circuit between A and B. Hence, no current passes through the resistor.

Now, in the last circuit, two different voltages 12V and 9V are supplied. Now, I want to know what would be the voltage reading at point B when the circuit is supplied with two different voltages? Whether current passes through the resistor as well or through the resistor as well as the bulb?

[image: 12V]

Comment: Point 'B' and point '12V A' are the same node in the circuit (assuming ideal wires with no resistance). You can't have 2 different voltages at one node. So what does that ell you about the voltage at 'B'?

Comment: your diagram is unclear ... you cannot have node A at 9 V and at 12 V at the same time ... it would make more sense to name one of the nodes C instead

Comment: i have corrected the name of the node as C

Answer (score 1):

there will be 12V in point B, as there are no resistors, or any other loads between it, and 12V source. The current will flow through the resistor, as there is 3V potential difference across it.